# DNS problems : correct nameserver, namserver working, but not resolving

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

My problem is as follows.  Any suggestions are welcome.

[domain].org is not resolving

whois and checking the registry information shows that the correct nameserver is set.

The primary nameserver is also the server on which domain.org is hosted.

The primary nameserver is also used for a number of other domains, and is working fine for those.

Logging into the server, I can ping [domain].org and it resolves correctly.

Setting the nameserver as my own DNS server on my laptop, and the URL resolves correctly.

If the domain has the correct nameserver set, and the nameserver can resolve the URL to the correct IP address, and if I use the nameserver as my DNS then it resolves correctly, AND the nameserver is used for other domains which are resolving correctly, then why isn't it working?

NB : this is a new domain registration and has been set up for around 10 days now, so it's not simple slow propagation.

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: I order to test the DNS you could use "host" or "dig" command to ask DNS servers directly to tell which server is failing.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you should check:

1) `dig @8.8.8.8 domain.org`, or some other external nameserver that isn't the one you're currently using or that one. You can also try going through a proxy to check out the domain. This will tell you if it's something in your local setup that's conflicting or if it's a general issue.

2) You may need to clear your local DNS cache, which may have cached an earlier answer and is still holding onto it - though unlikely after that long.

3) If your nameserver is set up like mine, it may have an external and internal side and handle differently depending on the requesting IP. You may have set up the domain on either side and not the other so it's only showing externally and not to you internally or vice versa.

4) Recheck the zone file and `named.conf` (assuming you're using bind) for typos. Potentially it's not actually working internally and you have a leftover `/etc/hosts` line that makes it look like it's working.

5) Restart the named service [again], I assume you've done this to get it working internally, but again something else may be making that work. To get it serving out the right resolution you're going to have to restart the service to get it to re-read all the zone files and config file(s).